# JQuery Horizontal Scrolling of Lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using php to add image thumbnails to lists...

For example: - The output would be...

```
<ul>
<li><img src="images/image1.png" /></li>
<li><img src="images/image2.png" /></li>
<li><img src="images/image3.png" /></li>
<li><img src="images/image4.png" /></li>
<li><img src="images/image5.png" /></li>
<li><img src="images/image6.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

This is showing in horizontal view so one beside the other and 6 fit in the page.

What I need to do is to have all one them loading at once but just 6 showing and have a "view more" button that I can press and will then show the next 6 and so on.

Anyone know of a JQuery plugin for this or can point to a script?

Comment: http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/horizontal.html

Comment: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-thumbnail-scroller

Comment: logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/horizontal.html is the right idea of what I need but that script just seems to scroll automatically?

Comment: Ya.. But i think u have study more about it.. if i will found anything else i will give u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you're looking for is called carousel, take your pick: [50+ Best jQuery Carousel Roundup](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/01/jquery-carousel.html)